# Подсчет методов Python с помощью декоратора функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, декоратор

Помогите разобраться с декораторами.

Функция которая будет у пользователя брать python объект и выводить все его  методы в списке, кроме dunder methods.

```
def method_name():
    """ Функция выдает заданные методы, без dunder methods """
    dunder_logic = [method for method in dir(tuple) if
                    method.startswith('__') is False]  
   return dunder_logic


  call_foo = method_name

  print(call_foo())
```

Так как в dunder_logic, указан dir(tuple), он выводит:

```
['count', 'index']
```

Я написал декоратор к это функции, который должен выводить количество методов, без dunder methods.

```
def methods_amount():
   """ Декоратор должен выдавать количество методов в функции def method_name """

def wrapper(count_method):
    count = 0
    for element in count_method:
        count += element
    return count_method

return wrapper
```

Вывод должен быть таким:

```
[count, index]
2
```

И к функции def method_name(), еще один декоратор, который будет принимать аргументом текст и по итогу 3 вывод должен выводить:

```
 @methods_amount('need to learn')
    [count, index]
    'need to learn 2'
```

По итогу с использование декоратора @methods_amount, выводит ошибку TypeError.

TypeError: methods_amount() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

Если убрать декоратор @methods_amount, то все работает и выводит то что нужно, а именно:

```
['count', 'index']
```

А необходимо, чтобы декоратор подсчитывал количество выводимых методов:

```
[count, index]
2
```

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь. (А у вас просто какое-то изложение, что вы делаете)

Comment: @Сергей Исправил самом описание проблемы. Ошибка состоит в том, что при использовании декоратора подсчета количество методов, интерпретатор выводит TypeError.